# Javascript: find text encolses with curly bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to get all text inside curly bracket.

Look at below variable value:

```
var str = "Hi {my} name {is} dev {garcia}";
```

I want to get array as below;

```
var extractedwords = [my,is,garcia]
```

I think, here I should use regex for extracting all strings closed with curly brackets and then push all into array.

I need help for regex operation for finding strings enclosed with curly bracket.

Please help!

Comment: hi Rory, sorry i did not post my efforts, but i tried to find out better way to fix problem. next time i will remember. don't mind please!

Answer (score 4):

```
"Hi {my} name {is} dev {garcia}".match(/[^{]+(?=\})/g)
```

that regex says:

`[^{]+` - Match any character that is NOT a “{” between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`(?=\})` - Assert that the match ends with a "}" without actually collecting the char (positive lookahead), here since you're outside `[]` (a set) you have to escape `}` by saying: `\}`

running this produces:

```
> "Hi {my} name {is} dev {garcia}".match(/[^{]+(?=\})/g)
["my", "is", "garcia"]
```

Comment: That's some bad-ass regex. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regex.

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/nuRJe/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"Hi {my} name {is} dev {garcia}".match(/([^}{]+)(?=})/g);
```

It basically means, "match any set of characters (1 or more) that are not '{' nor '}' until you reach a '}' (but exclude the })

The function `match()` runs on a string and accepts an object of type RegEx

To learn more about regular expressions I suggest reading this:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Then go to a javascript console (in your browser developer tools) and play around with these commands.